# Amazon S3 response body after uploading file in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can not get the response body after uploading file in browser.But I can see the Etag in the response Header. I use ajax to upload file and I want to get the Etag of a file, So does anybody have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it from the header and resolve the problem.